# Where can I find diagrams detailing non-client dimensions of various types of windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface, system-information

I often find that I need to find the width or height of a part of a non-client area (sizeable tool window border width, for instance) and I have never come across a complete diagram of what part is what. Much of it I can guess, but I'd love to have a really good set of diagrams that match up with what's found in .Net's `SystemInformation` class.

Has anyone ever seen such a diagram from Microsoft or from somewhere else?

Edit:

The best so far is this kind of diagram:  http://dmms.kssh.ed.jp/~kitano/winfaq/11/11-1.gif

I'd love to see something a little more modern and more detailed, but the bounty time limit is up so bounty is awarded to Erik.

Answer (score 0):

This can and will differ in between OS'es and themes. You will need to use `SystemParametersInfo` passing e.g. `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` to retrieve your defaults, or send `WM_NCCALCSIZE` to get actual values for a given window.

EDIT: As @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED mentions, also look at GetSystemMetrics.

Comment: The values will change, but the meanings wont.  Which is what the question actually is.

Comment: @Eric: I know I can get the sizes and widths of various window parts, but I'm looking to find information about the *structure* of a window. For example: Is there a border at the top of the window, like there is at the bottom and sides? If I had a diagram, I could answer that question.

Comment: This is the part that will vary? Sorry, not sure I understand what you're asking, is this something you want in order to *design and choose* styles, or something you want in order to *solve positioning runtime* ?

Comment: Reading your comment on the other answer, I see what you're asking, you want something that visually describes what a metric actually measures (Such as http://dmms.kssh.ed.jp/~kitano/winfaq/11/11-1.gif )

Comment: @Erik: correct. I have no idea why such a diagram is hard to find. To me, it should be a no-brainer.

Comment: Maybe you should just make it and put it on an adsense site :)

Comment: I've given you the bounty since you came the closest with that little diagram.

Comment: Undeserved IMO, but thanks. And if you *do* make such a diagram, please tell :)

Comment: I've got some free time next week so.. maybe!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I've never seen any such diagram either.  There is a wealth of information in the User Interface Guidelines on MSDN, but nothing that visually shows what each SystemInformation/GetSystemMetrics item refers to.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I'm thinking I should spend a few hours and derive such a diagram myself. I'm guaranteed to come across the diagram I need once I've drawn my own.